# Sistema Web da erro depois de um tempo online

Tags: java-ee, servidor, tomcat

Tenho um sistema web em um servidor, estou usando `tomcat` e o sistema está funcionando beleza, só que quando fica um tempo sem alguém entrar no sistema ele para de funcionar. Por exemplo eu vou embora do trabalho e deixo o sistema rodando no servidor, quando volto no dia seguinte e tento entrar da erro.

Minhas dúvidas são as seguintes: O que pode ser esse problema?

Trecho do Erro no log do `tomcat`:

```
25-Jun-2015 08:10:38.757 WARN [http-nio-8080-exec-49] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
25-Jun-2015 08:10:38.757 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-49] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: Software caused connection abort: socket write error

STACKTRACE:

java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:2744)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1612)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3283)
```

Comment: O arquivos de `logs` do `Tom cat` não te mostra nenhum informação ? @Techies

Comment: vou procurar esse arquivo

Comment: achei e editei a pergunta com o erro.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7747693/3861347 @Techies da uma olhada, não consigo te ajudar muito agora.

Comment: Ainda sim não entendi muito bem, será que pode ser algo relacionado ao meu pool de conexão?

Comment: Pelo que li, ele rejeita sua conexão.
quando eu tiver um tempo no trabalho dou uma olhada! @Techies

Comment: Beleza, estarei aguardando. Obrigado

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: @EduardoSeixas Não consegui resolver da forma que queria, fiz uma "gambiarra" mas gostaria de resolver da maneira certa

Comment: Seu problema está muito generico. O log fala que você tem um problema de conexão Communications link failure due to underlying exception. Para alguém te ajudar, teria que ter mais informações entende? Pode ser um problema de rede, fora da sua aplicação. Como foi essa sua gambiarra? Você mexeu no seu código e o erro desapareceu?

Comment: Caso você tenha conseguido resolver seu problema de um jeito ou de outro, poste a resposta mesmo assim. Você mesmo pode responder e marcar sua resposta como aceita, pois assim, por mais que seu código não esteja dos melhores, ele pode ajudar alguém que está desesperado por ao menos uma "gambiarra", que na emergência sabemos que ajuda. Depois, com base em mais informações, e mais entendimento do erro, você faz outra pergunta com mais informações, assim facilita a ajuda. Vamos evitar dessa forma que sua pergunta fique órfã de resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o Problema fazendo uma Thread que faz uma consulta de 1 em 1 hora no banco. Dessa forma sempre há uma "ligação" com o banco e a conexão não cai. Porém recentemente recebi uma dica do @rray que seria adicionar uma propriedade na configuração do hibernate:

```
<property name="connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
```